# Getting latest posts in a category on a forum

Tags: mysql, sql

Am trying to make an SQL query that will fetch every category from a DB and join them with the latest post in the category.

I use MySQL

The hierarchy of the contents is as so

**Category > Forum > Posts**

and this is a description of these tables

**Categories**

```
+-------+---------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type                      | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title | varchar(100)              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| icon  | varchar(100)              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| color | set('red','green','pink') | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Forums**

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title       | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| subtitle    | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| category_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Posts**

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+------------------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default|  Extra        |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+--------+---------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL   |auto_increment |
| title      | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL   |               |
| content    | longtext         | NO   |     | NULL   |               |
| forum_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL   |               |
| slug       | varchar(100)     | NO   | MUL | NULL   |               |
| created_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | TS     |               |
| updated_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000   | on update CTP |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+------------------------+
```

So to get the latest posts from each category, I have been able to make a query that actually gets what I want, but I don't think its the best possible way, will appreciate a smarter way, this is what I came up with

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT `categories`.`id`,
               `posts`.`title`      AS post_title,
               `categories`.`title` AS cat_title,
               `posts`.`created_at` AS created
        FROM   `categories`
               JOIN `forums`
                 ON `forums`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id`
               JOIN `posts`
                 ON `posts`.`forum_id` = `forums`.`id`
        ORDER  BY `created` DESC
        LIMIT  18446744073709551615) AS sub
GROUP  BY `id`
```

**===================EDIT====================**

**Sample Category Table**

```
+------------------------+-----------+----------+
| id| title              | icon      | color    |
+------------------------+-----------+----------+
| 1 | General Forums     | fa-pencil | red      |
| 2 | Help & Disscussion | fa-person | blue     | 
+---+--------------------+--------+------+------+
```

**Sample Forum Table**

```
+------------------------------+----------------------+--------------+
| id| title                    | subtitle             | category_id  |
+------------------------------+----------------------+--------------+
| 1 | Software Development     | About software dev   | 1            |
+---|--------------------------|----------------------|--------------|
| 2 | Graphics Design          | About graphics des   | 2            |
+---+--------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------|
```

**Sample Post Table**

```
+---+---------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+
| id| title               | content         | forum_id | slug       | created_at          |
+-------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 1 | Memoizing in JS     | Lorem Ipsum     | 1        |  memo-js   | 2019-03-21 00:45:54 |
+---+---------------------+----------------------------+------------+---------------------+
| 2 | Using headers in C# | Lorem Ipsum     | 1        | using-he   | 2019-03-20 00:45:54 |
+---+---------------------+-----------------+----------+----------------------------------+
```

So for each category, i need the latest post based on date created

**This is a dump of the database** [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZGyxYR2d1luN8apjLym9dEybmqAQoOmn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Sample data and desired output would be really helpful.

Comment: okay, i will add samples below the the output is getting the most recent post from each category based on the date it was created

Comment: I will add sample data in a bit

Comment: added sample data

Comment: You'll need to list a DBMS. SQL is standard, not a language in itself. Are you using Oracle, MySQL, etc?

Comment: Which dbms???  The query is different for different dbms.  It's useless if you get answer for different dbms, and can't use it.  It'll be a waste of everbody's time.

Comment: So from the table design, we can derive that the two forum posts belongs to software dev forum based on their `forum_id` foreign key and we can also see that software dev forum belongs to general forums' category, i want all most recent posts in a derived table containing the category and the post

Comment: Am using MYSQL db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely not the correct way.  You are using `GROUP BY` with `SELECT *` which is not supported by most databases and not even supported by more recent versions of MySQL using the default settings.

Instead:

```
SELECT c.id, p.title as post_title, c.title as cat_title,
       p.created_at AS created
FROM categories c JOIN
     forums f
     ON f.category_id = c.id JOIN
     posts p
     ON p.forum_id = f.id
WHERE p.created_at = (SELECT MAX(p2.created_at)
                      FROM posts p2 JOIN
                           forums f2
                           ON p2.forum_id = f2.id
                      WHERE f2.category_id = f.category_id
                     )
ORDER  BY created_at DESC;
```

The subquery is calculating the maximum created at date for the posts for a given category.

Comment: would be grateful if you can explain the subquery the WHERE clause in it actually, i understand everything else

Answer (score 0):

This should give what you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT c.id, p.title AS post_title, c.title AS cat_title, p.created_at AS created
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY p.created_at) AS rn
  FROM categories c
  JOIN forums f ON f.category_id = c.id
  JOIN posts p ON p.forum_id = f.id
) a
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: `MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY p.created_at) AS rn
  FROM categories c
  JOIN for' at line 4`

Comment: @olayemii `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY p.created_at) AS rn`